# Twitter dataset filtering for only English language text using Python

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, text-mining, tweets

Is there a way to filter already processed dataset for only English language text using Python? Maybe some NLTK features or something like that. The data was extracted from Twitter, and it's format is the following:

```
<tweetid>, <username>, <userid> &8888 <tweet text>
```

Stream filtering is not appropriate, since I have the initial data only in the format showed above.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the language detection module.

```
from textblob import TextBlob    
textBlob('your tweet').detect_language()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.